# how to plot geocoordinates on the map in realtime in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elk, kibana-7

[image: This is what i have tried so far and i have enabled the option of stream live data in the logs]

So I am trying to figure out a way in which the map is plotted in real time i am confused and do not know how to go about this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your needs, you want to refresh your data in near real time on the map.
If so you can just set refresh every X seconds > then push start at the bottom of the quick time selection.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a beginner could you guide me from where can I learn ? I am unable to find good sources which clear the concepts in depth

Comment: At first, the official documentation is quite good. https://www.elastic.co/guide/index.html and you can follow the free online trainings of elastic https://www.elastic.co/fr/training/free. Youtube is also a good source for training on kibana. I you need consulting to speed up your project you can contact my company on https://spoon-elastic.com/. And please, don't forget to upvote and validate the answer

Comment: Thank you @Jaycreation